# XML property task strips text node trailing spaces

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

This is the xml file, the Ant script is reading from:

```
<a>
  <b>This is a.b&#32;</b>
</a>
```

And this is in **build.xml**:

```
<echo>${a.b}</echo>
```

I expect to see this string: `'This is a.b '`(there is a space at the end of the string).

Instead I am getting this message: `'This is a.b'`(there is no trailing space).

The question is: What should I write within the `<b/>` element, in order to get this echoed string '`This is a.b '`? In other words, how to avoid normalizing the text node into the element when evaluated?

Comment: Would a non-breaking space &#160; help? Use &#160; instead of &#32;

Comment: Are you loading the XML file with [`<xmlproperty>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html)?

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies.  `&#160;` is passed literally. Output: `This is a.b&#160;`.   `&#32;` is rendered to this `This is a.b`.  
Yes I am loading the file with `<xmlproperty>`.